# Keeping the default left column in a facebook application?

Tags: facebook

I would like to keep the default left column in a facebook-application, is this possible somehow? Also is it possible to manipulate the default right column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do u mean with "default left column" and "default right column" ?

Do you mean with the left column the column where you can see friends or fans and stuff?
Do you mean with the right column the advertisement column?

If so: yes you can keep the left one when using a Facebook-Tab App. But this only works on Pages not on user profiles.
And afaik you can't change the advertisement column. This is generated by the "user-tracking-system" of facebook.

Comment: Is it possible to keep the left column in canvas applications?